# R - Improve performance of caret::train function

Tags: r, machine-learning, parallel-processing

I'm trying to run the `train()` function from the `caret` package. However, the time it takes to run is making it prohibitive. I've tried improving the speed by running on multiple cores, but even so... it's still loading. Are there any other alternative ways to speed up machine learning processes like this?

```
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)
library(caret)
library(mlbench)
library(caret)

data(Sonar)

inTraining <- createDataPartition(Sonar$Class, p = .75, list=FALSE)
training <- Sonar[inTraining,]
testing <- Sonar[-inTraining,]

cluster <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)
registerDoParallel(cluster)

trControl <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 5, allowParallel = T)
system.time(fit <- train(x,y, method="rf",data=Sonar,trControl = trControl))

stopCluster(cluster)
```

Comment: How big is the Sonar data? Have you tried fitting a random forest to the data without using `caret`?

Comment: Try reducing the number of features in your data using a technique such as PCA or ICA. You can also decrease the number of cv iterations in training although this increases the chance of overfitting.

Comment: Your code is not reproducible, what are the `x` and `y` in the train call? Why do you use the whole Sonar data for training if you made the train and test set previously? The following code: `system.time(train(Class ~ ., method="rf",data = training,trControl = trControl))` outputs 2.5 s on 1 core on my machine, perhaps you are not specifying the model correctly.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of steps you can take:

1. Reduce the number of features in your data using Principal Components Analysis ([PCA](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~tom/10601_fall2012/slides/pca.pdf)) or Independent Component Analysis ([ICA](https://danieltakeshi.github.io/2015/01/03/independent-component-analysis-a-gentle-introduction/)). You can use `caret::Preprocess` to do this. You can also remove unimportant features if you run the random forest and inspect the feature importances.
2. Try using the [ranger library implementation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ranger/ranger.pdf) of random forest. Set `method = 'ranger'` in the training call. I have found ranger is often quicker.
3. Decrease the number of [cross validation](https://www.openml.org/a/estimation-procedures/1) steps. This decreases the number of splits of the data and effectively the number of training iterations.

Answer (score 1):

Many times I use caret but it seemed very slow, now I use the h2o package, it is very fast. I recommend reading this [article](http://datascience.la/benchmarking-random-forest-implementations/) and see why my decision. Now using the Sonar base, generate this code.

```
# Starts H2O using localhost IP, port 54321, all CPUs,and 6g of memory 
data(Sonar,package = "mlbench")
library(h2o)
h2o.init(ip = "localhost", port = 54321, nthreads= -1,max_mem_size = "6g")
Sonar.split = h2o.splitFrame(data = as.h2o(Sonar),ratios = 0.75)
Sonar.train = Sonar.split[[1]]
Sonar.test  = Sonar.split[[2]]

#hyper_params <- list(mtries = c(2,5,10), ntrees = c(100,250,500), max_depth = c(5,7,9))
hyper_params <- list(mtries = c(2,5,10))
system.time(grid <- h2o.grid(x = 1:60, y = 61, training_frame = Sonar.train, validation_frame = Sonar.test,
                 algorithm = "drf", grid_id = "covtype_grid", hyper_params = hyper_params,
                 search_criteria = list(strategy = "Cartesian"), seed = 1234))

# Sort the grid models by logloss
sortedGrid <- h2o.getGrid("covtype_grid", sort_by = "logloss", decreasing = FALSE)
sortedGrid
```

lBoth for the algorithm with caret and with h2o use the syste.time function the results were as follows: with `caret 20.81 seconds` with `h2o 1.94 seconds`. the execution time is more evident with larger data.